# Replace specific data in table by ID with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-modal, laravel-blade

1. In my Laravel project I have a table where data is supposed to be updated without page reload in a specific row with jquery. Data has to be updated in the row:

```
....
  <tbody>
  @foreach ($tasks as $task)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$task->id}}</th>
      <td>{{$task->project_id}}</td>
      <td>{{$task->t_title}}</td>
      <td>
      <a href="#" class="editbtn btn btn-success ">EDIT </a>
      <a class="btn btn-success">DELETE </a> </td>
      </tr>
  @endforeach
```

2. Data is taken from there to Edit pop up form:

```
<form id="editFormID">
 <div class="modal-body">   
  @CSRF
  {{method_field('PUT')}}
  <input type="hidden"  name="id" id="id">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Project ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="project_id" id="project_id" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="t_title" id="t_title" class="form-control"  > ...
```

3. Data is taken from 1 to 2 by jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.editbtn').on('click', function() {
    $('#studenteditmodal').modal('show');

$tr = $(this).closest('tr');
var data = $tr.children("td").map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
console.log(data);
$('#id').val(data[0]);
$('#project_id').val(data[1]);
$('#t_title').val(data[2]);
 });

$('#editFormID').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id= $('#id').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "/studentupdate/"+id,
    data: $('#editFormID').serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      $('#studentEditModal').modal('hide');
      alert("Data Updated");
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
 });
});
```

After Submit jquery updates the data in the database without page reload, but to see it in the table I need to reload the page.

I would like to see the data in the table without reload. The idea would probably be:

After Submit -> Take ID from edit form (2) -> Find the row with this ID in the table (1) -> and update project_id and t_title cells.

How would I implement it?

Comment: You can write another function to fetch the record and update the table or you can update the entered values in the table after successful response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options here

1. A difficult (and ideal) one:

   - write an API in your Laravel application to fetch record by ID and update the record in the table.
2. A simple one:

   - Simply update the record in the table by updated field values.

here are the changes required for the simple approach:

```
<tbody>
  @foreach ($tasks as $task)
    <tr id="TaskNo{{ $task->id }}">
      <td class="id">{{$task->id}}</th>
      <td class="project_id">{{$task->project_id}}</td>
      <td class="t_title">{{$task->t_title}}</td>
      <td>
      <a href="#" class="editbtn btn btn-success ">EDIT </a>
      <a class="btn btn-success">DELETE </a> </td>
      </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Added ID in the parent tage to identify unique row.

Updating the row in Jquery

```
...
success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    $('#studentEditModal').modal('hide');
    $('#TaskNo'+ id +' .id').html($('#id').val());
    $('#TaskNo'+ id +' .project_id').html($('#project_id').val());
    $('#TaskNo'+ id +' .t_title').html($('#t_title').val());
    alert("Data Updated");
},
...
```

That should work.